# How can I add to a pandas column based on another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Currently I have a table that looks like this

```
ID       Previous_Injuries    Currently_Injured      Injury_Type
1            Nan                      0                  Nan
1            Nan                      1                  Ankle
1            Nan                      0                  Nan
1            Nan                      1                  Wrist
1            Nan                      0                  Nan
1            Nan                      1                  Leg
1            Nan                      0                  Nan
2            Nan                      1                  Leg
2            Nan                      0                  Nan
```

I would like to add to the Previous Injuries Column and make my table look like this:

```
ID       Previous_Injuries    Currently_Injured      Injury_Type
1            Nan                      0                  Nan
1            Nan                      1                  Ankle
1            [Ankle]                  0                  Nan
1            [Ankle]                  1                  Wrist
1            [Ankle,Wrist]            0                  Nan
1            [Ankle,Wrist]            1                  Leg
1            [Ankle,Wrist,Leg]        0                  Nan
2            Nan                      1                  Leg
2            [Leg]                    0                  Nan
```

How can I achieve this sort of a column in pandas? And is it best to do it in the form of a list?

Thanks!

Comment: Usually storing `list`s (or other objects) in a DataFrame is inefficient and makes other manipulations much more complicated. Though *sometimes* it can be fine if your data aren't huge. What do you need to do with this information after?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
df['Previous_Injuries']=( df['Injury_Type'].replace('Nan',np.nan).fillna(' ')
                                          .cumsum().shift(fill_value='')
                                          .str.split() )
print(df)
```

**`replace('Nan', np.nan)` can be omitted if the NaNs are not str**

---

```
   ID    Previous_Injuries  Currently_Injured Injury_Type
0   1                   []                  0         Nan
1   1                   []                  1       Ankle
2   1              [Ankle]                  0         Nan
3   1              [Ankle]                  1       Wrist
4   1       [Ankle, Wrist]                  0         Nan
5   1       [Ankle, Wrist]                  1         Leg
6   1  [Ankle, Wrist, Leg]                  0         Nan
```

Use [`DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) for differents ID

```
df['Previous_Injuries']=( df.groupby('ID')['Injury_Type']
                            .apply(lambda x: x.replace('Nan',np.nan).fillna(' ')
                                              .cumsum().shift(fill_value='')
                                              .str.split()) )
print(df)
```

---

```
   ID    Previous_Injuries  Currently_Injured Injury_Type
0   1                   []                  0         Nan
1   1                   []                  1       Ankle
2   1              [Ankle]                  0         Nan
3   1              [Ankle]                  1       Wrist
4   1       [Ankle, Wrist]                  0         Nan
5   1       [Ankle, Wrist]                  1         Leg
6   1  [Ankle, Wrist, Leg]                  0         Nan
7   2                   []                  1         Leg
8   2                [Leg]                  0         Nan
```

Comment: Good but why not just: `df['Injury_Type'].replace('Nan', ' ').cumsum().shift().str.split().bfill()`?

Comment: Thanks, made an edit to the post to include different IDs. Would the code change in that case?

Comment: You're right, the double use of replace is because I don't know if OP has Nan or np.nan values @Anton vBR

Comment: using np.nan @ansev

Comment: I added a solution for differents ID @soccer_analytics_fan

Answer (score 4):

We can do `shift` with `cumsum`, then `split` the string, Notice here you are using the `Nan`(string type) , which is not `np.nan`

```
s=df.Injury_Type.shift().fillna('Nan').add(',').cumsum().str[:-1].str.split(',')
df['new']=[[y  for y in x if y != 'Nan'] for x in s ]
df
Out[322]: 
   ID Previous_Injuries  Currently_Injured Injury_Type                  new
0   1               Nan                  0         Nan                   []
1   1               Nan                  1       Ankle                   []
2   1               Nan                  0         Nan              [Ankle]
3   1               Nan                  1       Wrist              [Ankle]
4   1               Nan                  0         Nan       [Ankle, Wrist]
5   1               Nan                  1         Leg       [Ankle, Wrist]
6   1               Nan                  0         Nan  [Ankle, Wrist, Leg]
```

Change the question again !

```
l=[]
for name , dfx in df.groupby('ID'):
    s = dfx.Injury_Type.shift().fillna('Nan').add(',').cumsum().str[:-1].str.split(',')
    dfx['new'] = [[y for y in x if y != 'Nan'] for x in s]
    l.append(dfx)

pd.concat(l)
```

Comment: Thanks, made an edit to the post to include different IDs. Would the code change in that case?

Comment: @soccer_analytics_fan groupby do it each group then concat